# Deploy dialogflow chatbot on Pepper?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, pepper

Is there any instruction manual or guidelines on how to deploy a Dialogflow chatbot on Pepper robot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the text of what the user said (in qiChat `u:(_*) $text=$1`) and forward it to an ALMemory event.

Then in Python or C++ subscribe to that event and code the boiler plate to send the text to the Google APIs.

Then Dialogflow will respond with the text, which you will have to send back to dialog through raising an ALMemory event (example `u:(e:answer) $answer`)

Jonas

Comment: Thanks for this method, although I ended up using an external speech recognizer which gave input to Dialogflow and Dialogflow's output was just sent to the Text-to-Speech of the Pepper robot. There are slight delays as Anders_K had forewarned but it's not too bad. I chose this method as Pepper's speech recognizer was not very good and the delays were much more significant when trying to use QiChat.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether u:(_*) $text=$1 can catch user's input. In case it works -> see here: https://qiita.com/egplnt/items/fe56b6c0169714bd871d
Otherwise, you need to ALAudioRecorder -> speech recognition -> dialogflow

Comment: Yeah, in fact it didn't work that well, as sometimes it just caught just one word. But in any case the speech recognition wasn't good enough so I used a different speech recognizer combined with TTS of Pepper for the interaction.

Comment: @rajput what speech recognizer did you use? Btw, dialogflow api v2 can process raw audio (using google speech).

Comment: I'm using the Uberi Speech Recognizer: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition. Although there are multiple speech recognition engines supported with it, I'm still using the Google speech recognizer. I wasn't aware that dialogflow api v2 can process raw audio. I'm using api v1 by the way in any case. But I'll keep it in mind if I decide to switch to v2 in future.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated Pepper with Dialogflow. My [blog](https://medium.com/@pwc.emtech.eu/pepper-integration-with-dialogflow-1d7f1582da1a) describes the code that runs external to Pepper to perform the integration. The blog does not go into detail about how to create a Dialogflow agent but the code to perform the integration is included.

It is not possible as Pepper users to install the necessary packages on Pepper. It must be run on a computer and operates Pepper remotely.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two are not compatible. You will have to write the code yourself.
Pepper is not designed to work with other chat systems than QiChat scripts.

Comment: Do you mean I could use Dialogflow's API to connect with QiChat and use it as a service?

Comment: It would require a large of work. How do you intend to capture the microphone signal of a user? And keep latency in mind for natural human conversation.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of using the same sensors used in case of QiChat but replace it with a chatbot. And I was wondering the same about the latency but the demos of Pepper Host Solution seem promising enough to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the US and if you purchased the Host solution (which contains a chatbot integration for DialogFlow and MSBot) you can follow the documentation here: https://softbankroboticstraining.github.io/pepper-chatbot-api/

Comment: Yes, I have been through that documentation, but unfortunately our lab doesn't have the Host solution. Just a Pepper.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether it is possible to use Dialogflow for Pepper without Host Solution.

Comment: Well, there is a way around Host Solution, if you are happy with using external speech recognizer and use only the Text-to-Speech (or Animated Text-To-Speech) of Pepper. I simply used Dialogflow's API and forwarded the responses to Pepper's TTS.